# Wordpress menu location deleted

Tags: php, wordpress, server, phpmyadmin, wordpress-theming

I purchased goodwill theme from edge and I have a problem with menus. I can not edit menus when I go appearance -> menus. 
The interesting thing is that I can create a menu from front-end editor, but as soon as I refresh the page it disappears. The menu items remained in their place, but the menu location got deleted.

I contacted support, gave them admin permissions. They tried, deactivated all plugins, changed the theme and concluded that problem is not theme but server.

What might be the problem on my server?

Comment: I have no idea what problem server can cause. They told me the problem is server or domain-related, not the theme.

Comment: if they didn't provided you full description and logs of issues, than you can be sure, that they lie, the only problem beetwen menu part and server might occured, when you have problems with mysql database. but if other parts of website working correctly, it's mean that you dont have problems with db

Comment: Samvel, I exported files from theme and site I am building and imported it to my local site using mamp server. On local site, everything works fine. I created new Wordpress site on  server, imported same files and problem was there.

Comment: I see. Then what logs, or suggestions provided you support? I can't sudjest you something until don't know anything about errors. Do you have any logs?

Comment: The support suggested me to change hosting. They said the problem is not on their side. I will attach error log on google drive here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzxPn54ti_piTDJraFptU05BV1U

Comment: add your logs to your question

Comment: I can not add it as a code becauase it is too big. And its over 512kB, so no purposose of paste bin.

Comment: then open access for everybody and add link into your question

Comment: I found what was the problem. There was a table in the database which was not populated correctly. After installing the local version I saw that my db on the server and my local database were different. I exported local database and imported on the server. After that, everything was fine.  
Thank you for your help. Regrads